# Filemaker 11 - Possible to upgrade web viewer

Tags: filemaker

I have to display some web content in FM11 via the web viewer, however the included web viewer is IE7 :(

Is there anyway to upgrade this or is it built in/closely coupled to FM and therefore not possible. I had assumed that FM would use whatever version of IE was installed on the local machine.

Any suggestions would be great - I would HATE to have to build this for IE7 in 2014 :)

Update: Sorry FileMaker is FM Pro 11.0v3 Advanced NOT 12

Client OS is Windows 7 & 8 and server is Windows Server 2003 R2

Comment: what operating system, and what exact version of FileMaker are you using. It matters

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer do you have installed on the machine you're trying to use the webviewer on? I believe FileMaker piggybacks off of the version of IE on windows or Safari on apple to generate it's content. If the computer you're trying to use the webviewer on has IE7 you could try installing a newer version of IE to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: IE11 installed - unfortunately it doesn't seem to use the installed IE, so it seems I am stuck with IE7 until we upgrade FMP

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it is part of FileMaker.  They have upgraded the webviewer in recent versions but you are stuck with what you have in FMP11.